# Align (distribute) images horizontally in Word with VBA macro

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, alignment

This is my first time writing macro in VBA. My goal is to write a ***VBA macro*** that will **automatically align (distribute) all images in a Word document horizontally (next to each other) with a small margin on each side of every image**. If there is not enough space to fit another image, I need it to go to the next row(just below previous images) and continue with the horizontal alignment of images.

I have searched a lot on the internet, but I haven't found a way to achieve this...

**NOTE: My macro already contains code for making all images have the same height(while keeping the same aspect ratio), so I think dimensions shouldn't be a problem...**

Here is a small example of what I want to achieve:
[image]

I tried using code for Horizontal alignment from this link: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/align-space-distribute-shapes/

But I got the following result:
[image]
Margins are weird and shapes are aligned infinitely instead of going into the next row...

**My Code:**

```
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim dTop As Double
    Dim dLeft As Double
    Dim dWidth As Double
    Const dSPACE As Double = 8 'Set space between shapes in points
    
    lCnt = 1
        
    Dim image As Shape

If ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
    For Each image In ActiveDocument.Shapes
         With image
             .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
             .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
             .Height = InchesToPoints(3)
             
            If lCnt > 1 Then
                .Top = dTop
                .Left = dLeft + dWidth + dSPACE
            End If
            dTop = .Top
            dLeft = .Left
            dWidth = .Width
         End With
         lCnt = lCnt + 1
    Next
   End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try by your own?

Comment: I recommend you use a table and you set the table properties not to automatically resize. For visual layout interest, you can make the rows have a different number of cells, much like your example. Turn the table borders off. I'm suggesting a table because otherwise, your code will have to be too complex allowing for different sized pictures and remaining page width.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have updated my question, so now it contains my code and more info...

Comment: @RichMichaels Thank you very much for answer! I will definitely try it, but I wanted to achieve the same thing but with macros, so I can automate it as much as possible... My macro already contains code for resizing all images to the same height, so I think that dimensions shouldn't be that huge problem?

Comment: Use a table with 1 column the width of the page as you indicate, and each row the same height. The all your code need to worry about is placing the pictures in a cell side by side and the table takes care of the rest. You.

Comment: You can use your actual code creating two new variables `totalWidth` and `totalHeight`. You have to compare the `totalWidth` with printable page with and make `totalWidth` zero and `Top` to pe equal with `totalHeight` plus `dSpace`. Of course, you previously must calculate the theoretical `totalWidth` and use a new picture line if it exceeds the page width.

Comment: @Boeryepes Wow, interesting solution! I will try that, too... Thank you for answer!

Comment: @FaneDuru That's the exact solution that I am currently trying to implement! Thank you very much for your answer and idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting your images into a table with fixed cell dimensions won't achieve what you say you want, since the images clearly don't have the same aspect ratio. What you need to do is to convert them to inlineshapes so that Word can handle the line wrapping. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim iShp As InlineShape
With ActiveDocument
  Do While .Shapes.Count > 0
    .Shapes(1).ConvertToInlineShape
  Loop
  For Each iShp In .InlineShapes
    With iShp
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      .Height = InchesToPoints(3)
      If .Range.Characters.Last.Next <> " " Then .Range.InsertAfter " "
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You can adjust the vertical spacing between the images by changing the paragraph line spacing. Note too, that the horizontal alignment can be played around with by switching between left, centered and justified paragraph formats.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am amazed by your answer and I learned a lot of new stuff from it! I have one additional question... Is there any way that I can specify the horizontal space between images instead of inserting just a single space after each image?

Comment: «Is there any way that I can specify the horizontal space between images instead of inserting just a single space after each image?» Not with in-line shapes. You can, of course use different size spaces (e.g. by changing the font name and/or size) and/or use multiple spaces.

Comment: Well, it's good to know that, too... Thank you very much for help!

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you, but I have one more question... I am currently adding more additional options to my macro, and I have faced this problem: Each time I run the macro, it adds additional space after each image...Is there any option to remove spaces after images or something like that, so I can reset a number of spaces to 0 each time I run macro? I know how to ask the user for input, so I will make for loop to add a certain number of spaces, my only problem is to remove spaces that were generated by previous macro call...

Comment: I didn't know that it can be done like this... I am still a beginner at VB, so sorry If I ask stupid questions... This works for a single space, but if I try to do the same with multiple spaces (I have deleted all images and imported them again to try with more spaces), I can still add spaces infinitely each time I run the macro... Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: The IF test in the revised code (i.e. If .Range.Characters.Last.Next <> " " Then) should work regardless of how many spaces you insert between the images.

Comment: You're right. I made a stupid mistake, sorry. I added more spaces in both strings, instead of just adding more spaces in the second string and leaving only one space in the first string... Now it works! Thank you very much, I learned a lot from your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to VBA I wanted to share a bit of code if you were to pursue a Table approach. The code below creates a single-row table that is fixed in width and will not expand width-wise unless you alter the individual cells. For demo purposes only, I insert the same picture into each cell to demonstrate that the image resizes automatically based on cell width.

```
Sub TableOfPictures()
    Dim doc As Word.Document, rng As Word.Range
    Dim Tbl As Word.Table, C As Long
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    
    Set Tbl = rng.Tables.Add(rng, 1, 2, Word.WdDefaultTableBehavior.wdWord8TableBehavior)
    Tbl.rows(1).Cells(1).Width = InchesToPoints(2)
    Tbl.rows(1).Cells(2).Width = InchesToPoints(4.5)
    For C = 1 To 2
        Tbl.rows(1).Cells(C).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("Y:\Pictures\Mk45 Gun Proj_Blast.jpg")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool, this is definitely an interesting approach that can be adjusted to fit my needs. I didn't know that tables could be used for problems like this... Thank you very much for help and idea!